# Create Report with AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, report

How to create a simple report with AS3 Flash then print it (since there is no report engine in Flash) ?

My app (developed in Flash) is a simple survey form, so peoples use it to fill their answers, then there is a button to review their answer (like Microsoft Word **print preview** page, before you print it).

Its better addition if we can export it to pdf or excel format

Comment: There is no report builder in flash. Googled? Not found.. You can checked it using my question

Comment: there is plenty of possibilities - none will give you automatic solution. Also what is lack from your question is subject of the report - so what do you want to report? anyways you have to build report functionality then: a) create custom MovieClip that will contain those "pages" sent to printer, b) create the PDF and save it which then can be printed, c) use AS3XLS to create Excell spreadsheet with your report, d) prepare in Excell the report template, save as XML and use it in your customly build report and so on...

Comment: What do you mean by a report engine? Sounds like a debugger is what you need.

Comment: @David: report engine like freereport in Delphi, so we can easily create a report.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to do it is generate a HTML page from as3 and execute it with default browser and let the user print from there.